# Как использовать babel внутри строк в шаблонах Vue?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babel

Мне нужна функциональность [`optional chaining`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) внутри шаблонов `{{ ... }}` , `v-bind:...=" ... "` , `v-on:...=" ... "` и т.д.

Результат:

[image: ошибка]

На данный момент разработчики Vue отказываются ([1](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8861), [2](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6307)) реализовывать babel-прекомпиляцию строковых шаблонов. Как можно решить это конфигурацией Webpack?

Comment: Вот здесь, https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6307#issuecomment-345751066 - Evan, кажется ответил

Comment: Это плохая практика. Гораздо лучше выносить такие конструкции в геттеры.